# Disable WebStorm's notifications for running tests

Tags: intellij-idea, notifications, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a TypeScript project using Jest for tests. I have a project configuration to watch and run Jest tests. It works very well.

I do not want system notifications. I've already turned off notifications in System Preferences > Webstorm. When a test finishes running, it jumps in the Dock with a green check mark. I don't want to be notified at all, ever, for these tests being run.

How do I disable it?

Comment: Do you have *Enable system notifications* disabled in `Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Notifications`?

Comment: @Oksana That's it!

Comment: Actually, that didn't work :/